# Playing Audio in Android via AudioManager?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I play a sound using:

```
public class NotificationFunction implements FREFunction {
  public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
    Context appContext = context.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)     
    appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.loadSoundEffects();
    mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(0);
```

It plays a default sound effect, how can I get it to play a custom sound effect.

Also I have tried to implement sound pool but it doesnt work, I implemented it the standard way but it doesnt work. Any ideas why? Or if I can use the audio manager for sounds instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check with following code

```
using (AudioManager am= (AudioManager)WebViewActivity.Instance.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService))
        {
            int maxVol = am.GetStreamMaxVolume(Stream.Music);
            float myVol= maxVol  * volume;

            am.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Music, (int)(myVol), 0);

            using (SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, Stream.Music, 0))
            {
                int soundFileId = soundPool.Load(soundFilePath, 1);

                soundPool.LoadComplete += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    using (SoundPool soundPoolLoaded = sender as SoundPool)
                    {
                      soundPoolLoaded.Play(soundFileId, myVol, 
                                          myVol, 0, 0, 1.0f);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```